# wxPython layout using boxsizers

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I've recently started using wxPython to build a GUI and I'm trying to create the following layout:

```
Button1 Button2 Button3
----------------------------------------
listbox | textctrl
```

The buttons should have a flexible width, expanding to fill the full width of the frame with a border between them (each buttons has a width (incl. border) of 1/3 frame). Their height should be set to a height in pixels.

The listbox should fill the frame vertically and have a set width of x pixels

The textctrol should be a textbox which expands to fill the width of the frame vertically as well as horizontally.

This is the code I have:

```
mainPanel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
parentBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

menubar = wx.MenuBar()
filem = wx.Menu()

menubar.Append(filem, '&File')
self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

navPanel = wx.Panel(mainPanel, -1, size=(1000, 80))
navBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

newSection = wx.Button(navPanel, self.ID_NEW, 'New')
renSection = wx.Button(navPanel, self.ID_RENAME, 'Rename')
dltSection = wx.Button(navPanel, self.ID_DELETE, 'Delete')

navBox.Add(newSection, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
navBox.Add(renSection, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
navBox.Add(dltSection, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)          

navPanel.SetSizer(navBox)

contentPanel = wx.Panel(mainPanel, -1, size=(1000, 600))
contentBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

self.listbox = wx.ListBox(contentPanel, -1, size=(300, 700))
self.settings = wx.TextCtrl(contentPanel, -1)

contentBox.Add(self.listbox, 0)
contentBox.Add(self.settings, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

contentPanel.SetSizer(contentBox)

parentBox.Add(navPanel, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
parentBox.Add(contentPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

mainPanel.SetSizer(parentBox)
```

Something is going wrong since what I see is not what I expect to see, anybody who can help me out?

Comment: What is going wrong exactly? Some more details will help understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me, I'm on win64, python 32bit 2.7.3.3, wx '2.8.12.1 (msw-unicode)'. The full working test example is:

```
import wx

class testframe(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'some title')
        mainPanel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        parentBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        filem = wx.Menu()

        menubar.Append(filem, '&File')
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

        navPanel = wx.Panel(mainPanel, -1, size=(1000, 80))
        navBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        newSection = wx.Button(navPanel, -1, 'New')
        renSection = wx.Button(navPanel, -1, 'Rename')
        dltSection = wx.Button(navPanel, -1, 'Delete')

        navBox.Add(newSection, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        navBox.Add(renSection, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        navBox.Add(dltSection, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)          

        navPanel.SetSizer(navBox)

        contentPanel = wx.Panel(mainPanel, -1, size=(1000, 600))
        contentBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.listbox = wx.ListBox(contentPanel, -1, size=(300, 700))
        self.settings = wx.TextCtrl(contentPanel, -1)

        contentBox.Add(self.listbox, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        contentBox.Add(self.settings, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

        contentPanel.SetSizer(contentBox)

        parentBox.Add(navPanel, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        parentBox.Add(contentPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

        mainPanel.SetSizer(parentBox)
        parentBox.Fit(self)

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
app.frame = testframe()
app.frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Notice the addition of `Fit()` of the main sizer, and also 5px border added to the listbox.